# AddMailBoxPermission on Powershell ISE v5.1

Tags: powershell, mailbox

I am using powershell version 5.1 and trying to use Add-MailboxPermission, whenever I run that command I get the following error:

Add-MailboxPermission : The term 'Add-MailboxPermission' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- Add-MailboxPermission -Identity cbryant -User abedi -AccessRights Ful ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-MailboxPermission:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I looked up my exchange permissions, I have all the Admin Access, Tried removing the permission and adding it back again.
Made sure the ExchangeOnlineManagement Module was installed
Imported the module using the Import command as well
My manager is able to run the command the successfully we tried to check the permissions they are all identical and I made sure the powershell ISE was run as an admin.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you [connect to EXO after module import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps#connect-to-exchange-online-powershell-with-an-interactive-login-prompt)?

Comment: Yes, I did, In addition to that I followed all the steps on this link as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#install-and-maintain-the-exchange-online-powershell-module

Comment: Perhaps it's being aliased as `Add-EXOMailboxPermission`? Does `Get-Command *MailboxPermission*` show anything interesting?

Comment: Get-EXOMailboxPermission -Identity cbryant -User abedi
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ProtocolError: (:) [Get-EXOMailboxPermission], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : One or more errors occurred.,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient.GetExoMailboxPermission

Gives out this

Comment: If you inspect the error message closely, it'll probably say what's wrong - if it's complaining that it can't find a mailbox that you definitely know exists, then it's likely a permission problem - go back and verify that your account have the expected management roles assigned

Comment: It's complaining that it cannot find the commands, and I checked my permissions again and everything is fine over there